# I want to alert a value when I press the Esc button in prompt, but I have no idea... (code below)

Tags: javascript, key, keycode

```js
const login = prompt("Enter username!", "");

if (login === "Admin") {
  prompt("Enter password!");
} else if (login === "" || login.keyCode === 27) {
  alert("Canceled");
} else {
  alert("I don't know you!");
}
```

This is the error message when I press Esc:

'Cannot read properties of null (reading 'keyCode')
at logical-operators.html:77'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you press ESC the login value will become null so you can check like this:

```
if(!login){
  alert('cancled')
}
```

or you can add listener to dom if ESC clicked :

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Escape") {
      // escape key maps to keycode `27`
      alert('cancled')
    }
  });
```